# Xamarin Android Start app using link with parameters

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-intent, xamarin.android, intentfilter

I have a problem. I created a IntentFilter so my app launches when clicked on a specific link. Here is my IntentFilter:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
DataScheme = "myapplication.app"
)]
```

And here is the link:

```
<a href='myapplication.app://'>here</a>
```

But how can I pass a parameter (integer) in that link and how can I use that parameter in my C# code?

Comment: could it work now ?

Answer (score 0):

A complete URL Scheme protocol format consists of Scheme, host, port, path, and query. The structure is as follows:

```
<scheme>://<host>:<port>/<path>?<query>
```

and receive data in the called Activity like:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
DataScheme = "urlschemetest2",
DataHost = "testurl.com")]
```

the link :

```
<a href="urlschemetest2://testurl.com/?firstname=john&lastname=doe">Test Opening App</a>
```

get the parameter :

```
 protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
 {
   Android.Net.Uri uri  = Intent.Data;
   if(uri != null)
   {
      string firstName = uri.GetQueryParameter("firstname");
      string lastName = uri.GetQueryParameter("lastname");
   }
   base.OnNewIntent(intent);
 }
```

Comment: Where do I need to put the code to get the uri parameter?