# Xamarin Forms App Linking using parameters

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a question. I want to start my app from my php page and pass a variable over that link. Then on my app site, I need to read the parameter and perform the actions that I want with that parameter. Now I already found this link: [Xamarin Android Start app using link with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078568/xamarin-android-start-app-using-link-with-parameters). This person does that with `Xamarin.Android`. But how can I do this in `Xamarin.Forms`, or is it similar?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/deep-linking

Comment: As I can read the page, I can't use Deep-Linking if my app isn't in the playstore. Right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will show you how to do this by using the following url as an example: https://xamboy.com/hello/Rendy

- **xamboy.com**: Domain associated to app link
- **hello**: Is the app link path
- **Rendy**: The parameter

First, you need to configure app link support for each platform. By doing the following steps:

## Apple portal configuration

1. Go to App IDs section and click on your application

[image]

2. In the list of Application Services scroll to the bottom and click on Edit

[image]

3. Enable Associated Domains and Save.

[image]

## Website configuration

In order to verify the domain association with the application, is necessary to upload a file in the website that defines this association.

Need to create a file named apple-app-site-association. This file should contain the following json structure:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "CNAL8C4H5U.com.crossgeeks.applinkssample",
                "paths": [ "/hello/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Example: https://www.xamboy.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

This file should be placed inside .well-known folder or at the root path of the website (https://yourdomain/.well-known/apple-app-site-association).

- The appID is the combination of Prefix + (.) + ID
  [image]
- Paths is the definition of all the paths our application will handle if present on the url. For example in our case is https://xamboy.com/hello because we just defined /hello as a path in the apple-app-site-association file.
- apple-app-site-association file shouldn’t have a file extension

## Android Configuration

Need to create a Digital Assets file named assetlinks.json. There’s an online tool that assist you creating and testing this file here: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator.

It should contain the following json structure:

```
[
   {
      "relation":[
         "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
      ],
      "target":{
         "namespace":"android_app",
         "package_name":"com.crossgeeks.applinkssample",
         "sha256_cert_fingerprints":[
            "3E:5D:E5:3B:BC:5A:61:BC:9E:96:34:C7:C2:D6:9F:BB:32:3C:8E:C5:FD:CE:D2:76:4C:81:98:2F:41:12:15:DD"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Example: https://www.xamboy.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json﻿

This file should be placed inside .well-known folder of the website (https://yourdomain/.well-known/assetlinks.json).

If you want to test that everything is working fine you can do it by using this url:

https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site= https://:&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls

If everything is ok it should look similar to this:

[image]

## Configure App Linking in mobile projects

### iOS project

Go to the Entitlements.plist file, enable the property Associated Domain and add the domain of the website with the format applinks:yourdomain.com and applinks:*.yourdomain.com

[image]

### Android project

Configure app links on Android MainActivity by adding an IntentFilter per each domain/path/protocol you want to support.

```cs
[Activity(Label = "AppLinksSample", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
              MainLauncher = true,  
              ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]

    //Invite App Link
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
                  DataScheme = "https",
                  DataHost = "xamboy.com",
                  DataPathPrefix = "/hello",
                  AutoVerify =true,
                  Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
                  DataScheme = "http",
                  DataHost = "xamboy.com",
                  AutoVerify = true,
                  DataPathPrefix = "/hello",
                  Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]

    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        }
    }
```

### Forms project

In the App.cs file override the method OnAppLinkRequestReceived. This is where you handle what happens when your app is opened by an app link and process the parameters:

```cs
 protected override void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)
 {
      if (uri.Host.EndsWith("xamboy.com", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {

                if (uri.Segments != null && uri.Segments.Length == 3)
                {
                    var action = uri.Segments[1].Replace("/", "");
                    var msg = uri.Segments[2];

                    switch (action)
                    {
                        case "hello":
                            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg)){
                                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async() =>
                                {
                                    await Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("hello", msg.Replace("&", " "), "ok");
                                });
                            }

                            break;

                        default:
                            Xamarin.Forms.Device.OpenUri(uri);
                            break;
                    }
                }
     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can this be performed during development - I have tired on using below tutorial but the disambiguation dialog is never shown. Instead it opens on Chrome browser. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking