# How to fix Applink only open Safari Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am facing problem with AppLink in Xamarin iOS/ I followed the article https://www.xamboy.com/2019/01/08/applinks-in-xamarin-forms/. Everything I configured seems fine:

1. Enable Associated Domains
2. Website configuration (apple-app-site-association). I also checked on https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

   ```
   Your domain is valid (valid DNS).  Your file is served over HTTPS.
   Your server does not return error status codes greater than 400.
   Your file's 'content-type' header was found :)
   Your JSON is validated.
   ```

[image]

**iOS project**

Go to the **Entitlements.plist** file, enable the property Associated Domain and add the domain of the website with the format `applinks:mydomain.com` and `applinks:*.mydomain.com` and `applinks:mydomain` and `applinks:*.mydomain`

**PageOne.xaml.cs**

```
private async void _viewmore_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string linkapp = _linkapp.Text;
    await Browser.OpenAsync(linkapp, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
}
```

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url.ToString());
    var formsApp = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current;
    formsApp.SendOnAppLinkRequestReceived(uri);

    return true;
}
```

**App.cs**

```
protected override async void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)
{
    base.OnAppLinkRequestReceived(uri);

    if (uri.Host.ToLower() == "mydomain.com" && uri.Segments != null && uri.Segments.Length == 3)
    {
        string action = uri.Segments[1].Replace("/", "");
        bool isActionParamsValid = int.TryParse(uri.Segments[2], out int productId);
        if (action == "ProductDetail" && isActionParamsValid)
        {
            if (productId > 0)
            {
                App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView(1));
            }
            else
            {
                // it can be security attack => navigate to home page or login page.
                App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Clear, rebuild,... however I try clicking the _viewmore_Tapped link. It opens again on a Safari page. I checked it on click: Open in it also doesn't have anything related to my application.

[image]

How can it open directly in the app? I have consulted the posts, however it does not solve the problem. Looking for solutions from everyone. Thank you

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60433411/why-does-openurl-is-not-being-called-in-ios-13-but-it-does-in-ios-12-xamarin, BUT open issue here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13786, so I don’t know if anyone has solved.

Comment: I've looked at the posts you've submitted, and it doesn't seem to be resolved either :(

Comment: check the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/276838/deep-linking-does-not-work-in-xamarin-forms-where.html

Comment: I referenced it. However the problem is still not resolved, I don't get any error. It just automatically closes the app. Is it outdated?

Comment: so the link opened the app but then the app just closed automatically ?

Comment: Oh no, it closes the app by itself before I open the link

Comment: you can check this question which contains smoe detail about the sample you follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460529/xamarin-forms-app-linking-using-parameters

Comment: I followed that post. Everything works fine on Android, but on iOS it doesn't open the app on Safari?